# PHP "IF conditions"

Tags: php

Example 1)

```
       if(5 == $brandId)
       {
       }
```

Example 2)

```
       if($brandId == 5)
       {
       }
```

can somebody please explain the difference between this two conditions

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: There is no difference

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using common sense.

Comment: HamZa - To be fair everyone has to start somewhere, it isn't off topic as it is a programming site and this is a programming question.

Comment: Related: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions

Comment: @HamZa - But you might expect logically that 1 == "1" is false because one is a string and one is a number but it does evaluate to true. You have to learn somewhere that if you want that to happen you have to use 1 === "1". Not everything is completely logical and when you are learning a programming language you do wonder why people do things differently to you and I know I wanted to find out if there was any difference when I first started learning.

Comment: @cwyatt1 ok, I'll spill the beans: it's StackOverflow's closing mechanism that's broken. In the old days we could close this as "too localized". Basically if we were to accept every programming question we would pollute this wonderful database that is StackOverflow. Also the OP could just have tried the two expressions and would have noticed there's no difference.

Answer (score 2):

In first condition you have `5` compared with value of `$brandId`, while in second condition you have `$brandId` value compared with `5`.
It's only code style difference, because there is no difference (`5 == 5`)

Answer (score 1):

They work identically as you can say 5 == 4 + 1 or you can say 4 + 1 == 5. In that respect they are identical as both compute to true (as a boolean).

Answer (score 0):

One reason to use example 1 is if you typo it, like `if ($brandId = 5)`, then the `$brandId` will be overwritten with the value 5. I don't know any other differences between these two, I tend to use the latter (example 2), because I think its easier to read/understand.